# What is "Azalia internal HDMI codec" BIOS setting?

Tags: ubuntu, bios, hdmi

There's an Advanced setting in my BIOS that says "Azalia internal HDMI codec". It's currently off. Do I want this on or off? I can't even figure out what it is for.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit on a [laptop from ZaReason](http://zareason.com/shop/Strata-Pro-13.html). The BIOS is "Aptio Setup Utility" by "American Megatrends, Inc" version 2.00.1201.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azalia is the codename for Intel's [onboard audio card / codec specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio), Intel HD Audio.

The HDMI codec chip is responsible for preparing the output to be fed to the HDMI out. If you plan to use an HDMI cable to connect an HDMI cable from your laptop to an external source, you might want to turn it on